# array_push while loop shopping cart item into basket without javascript

Tags: php, html, sql

hello I want to add a cart item into a cart by using a button. For this I want to array_push this into my array. And then show that array into my cart. this is not what is happening right now:
right now it shows the last item from the while loop in the shopping cart and thats not what I want.
I want that if the user pressed the add_to_cart button then array_push this broodjes_ID, broodnaam, and prijs into the cart. what am I doing wrong?

index.php <- the shop

```
<!-- session_start();   session has already started -->
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errrors', '1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/stylecart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/scripts.js" async></script>

    </head>
    <style>
        body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        }

        #myBtn {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 30px;
        z-index: 99;
        font-size: 18px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 25px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        }

        #myBtn:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <?php include "navbar.php"?>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])){ ?>
        <!-- Header-->
        <header class="bg-dark py-5">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 my-5">
                <div class="text-center text-white"> <!--Het werkt -->
                    <h1 class="display-4 fw-bolder">Goedemorgen, <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME'];?></h1>
                    <p class="lead fw-normal text-white-50 mb-0">Shop in style</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
                <!-- Header-->
                <header class="bg-dark py-5">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 my-5">
                <div class="text-center text-white"> <!--het werkt-->
                    <h1 class="display-4 fw-bolder">Goedemorgen, Gast</h1>
                    <p class="lead fw-normal text-white-50 mb-0">Shop in style</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <?php } ?>
        <!--miscchien dit toch in een whileloop gooien dat zal ook de code korter maken-->
        <!-- Section-->
        <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">&#8593;</button> 
        <?php 
        include "config.php";
        $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM broodjes';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
            $_SESSION['basket'] = array(); 
            //echo $row['broodnaam'];
            echo '        <section class="py-5">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col mb-5">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <!-- Product image dit kan later nog wel-->
                            <div class="fw-image">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product details-->
                            <div class="card-body p-4">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div class="test1">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="broodjes_ID" value=', $row['broodjes_ID'] , '/>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Product name-->
                                    <div class="test3">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="broodnaam" value=', $row['broodnaam'] , '/>
                                        <h5 class="fw-bolder">'.$row['broodnaam']. '</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Product price-->
                                    <div class="test2">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="broodnaam" value=', $row['prijs'] , '/>
                                        <h3> Prijs:  </h3>   <h3 class="fw-price"> €'.$row['prijs']. '</h3><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--voorraad--> 
                                    '; if($row['voorraad'] == 0){
                                        echo '
                                        <h3 class="fw-voorraad" style="color: red;"> uitverkocht</h3><br>
                                    '; }else{ 
                                        echo ' 
                                        Voorraad: '.$row['voorraad'].'<br>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Product actions-->
                                        <form action="cart.php?broodjes_ID=', $row['broodjes_ID'] , '" method="post">
                                            <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                                                <div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto shop-item-button" type="submit" name="add_to_cart">Add to cart</button></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    '; } 
                        echo '</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>';                           

        }
        ?>
        
        <!-- Footer-->
        <?php include "footer.php";?>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scrolltotop.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

cart.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Cart</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/stylecart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/scripts.js" async></script>

    </head>

<?php 
include "config.php";
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM broodjes';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
    $_SESSION['basket'] = array(); 
    
    if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])){
            array_push($_SESSION['basket'], $row['broodjes_ID'], $row['broodnaam'], $row['prijs']);
        } 
        print_r($_SESSION['basket']);
    }
        ?>
        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 100px;">&#128717;</div>
        <h2 class="text-center">Winkelmandje</h2><br>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <!-- <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2> -->
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>  
            <?php 
               // query maken waarbij wij naam en prijs ophalen van de ids.
              
                $count = count($_SESSION['basket']);
                if($count > 0){
                    $sum = 0;
                    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
                        $basket =  $_SESSION['basket'][$i];
                        $sql = "SELECT broodjes_ID, broodnaam, prijs FROM broodjes WHERE broodjes_ID = ?";
                        // uitvoeren, resultaat tonen in tabel.
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bind_param("s", $basket); 
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
                        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){     
                            echo '<div class="cart-items">';
                            echo '<div class="cart-row">';
                            echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                            echo '<span class="cart-item-title">'. $row['broodnaam'] . '</span>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<span class="cart-price cart-column"> €'. $row['prijs'] . '</span>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            
                            $sum += $row['prijs']; 
                        }
                        
                    }
                ?>
                    <div class="cart-total">
                        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                        <span class="cart-total-price"> € <?php echo $sum;?></span>
                    </div>
            <?php

                }else{
                    echo 'mandje is leeg.';

            ?>
                <div class="cart-total">
                    <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                    <span class="cart-total-price"> € 0</span>
                </div>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>



            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" style="margin: 5%;" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: sidenote: FWIW your code is very difficult to read - have you considered separating html (view) and logic(php)? It might also help debugging and future maintenance.

Comment: The form you submit needs to specify the ID of the item you want to add to the cart. Otherwise, the PHP doesn't know which button was pressed.

Comment: $row['broodjes_ID'], $row['broodnaam'] and $row['prijs'] should be put in hidden fields in your form and you should push that (from $_POST) in the basket instead of the rows.
The hidden fields per form whould look like this: <input type='hidden' name='broodjes_ID' value='<? echo $row['broodjes_ID']?>'/>

The array_push can be moved outside of the while loop, because it only happens once per submit (POST), not per row.